# apt-get Aborted package lists

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Can't update. Any call apt-get return:

> Aborted package lists... 3%.

How fix it?

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [15.4 MB]
Get:3 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages [165 kB] 
Get:4 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages [109 kB]  
Fetched 15.7 MB in 10s (1522 kB/s)                                             
Aborted
Aborted package lists... 95%
root@kali:~# apt-get check
Aborted package lists... 3%
root@kali:~# apt-get install
Aborted package lists... 3%

root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.12.6-1kali6 (2017-08-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@kali:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.2 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170917-01:51]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.2 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170917-01:51]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

# deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

root@kali:~# apt-cache gencaches
Aborted package lists... 3%
root@kali:~# apt update
Get:1 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.volia.net/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [15.4 MB]
Fetched 15.4 MB in 12s (1271 kB/s)                                             
Aborted
Aborted package lists... 95%
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L . What is the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? [Please edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/398330/edit)

Comment: @GAD3R Update output.

Comment: `apt-cache  gencaches` then `apt update`

Comment: @GAD3R Update result.

Answer (score 2):

The line `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` seems problematic. If you copy and paste PART of it, it draws a blank - `http://http.kali.org/kali`

The Repository looks like it is now HTTP**S**

```
https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-repository-https-support/
```

I would change the line to `deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

If you try PART of that line, it works and takes you to `https://http.kali.org/kali/`

Comment: Thanks, but it is not help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help us to analyse the problem. What EXACTLY happened?

Answer (score 1):

Run `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to clear downloaded lists. This happens because of corrupted downloaded package lists. I'm not sure if there is any command in `apt-get` to delete them. [Reference here.](https://www.prolixium.com/blog?id=1025)